# Why does jQuery autocomplete input break with runat?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, input, autocomplete, runatserver

I am trying to use a simple `jQuery` autocomplete input in my `Asp.Net` web application:

**Summary.aspx**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var cityList = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewState["Cities"]) %>;
        $( "#uxCities" ).autocomplete({
            //source: availableTags
            source: cityList
        });
    });
</script>
...
<div class="ui-widget">
  <asp:Label for="Cities">City </asp:Label>
  <input id="Cities">
</div>
```

This solution works fine on the client-side. However, I need to grab whatever value/text the user enters in the input in the `.cs/C#` file as well. When I add `runat="server"` to `<input id="Cities">`, the jQuery breaks. Additionally, `input` doesn't seem to have an attribute that allows me to grab what the user enters like a texbox (ex: `string userCity = uxCities.Text;`). How can I get the `jQuery` autocomplete functionality on the client-side but still utilize the input value on the server-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch the client id of the textbox like this:

```
<input id="Cities" runway=“server” />

$('#<%=Cities.ClientID%>').autocomplete({..});
```

Comment: OK, this works, but there is no attribute `runway` so I changed it to `runat="server"` and it worked. One question: I need whatever is in that input box (whatever the user chooses or types) as an input parameter on the server side. Since there is no `.Text` attribute for an input, what could I use?

Comment: I believe you can use Cities.Value